# C# Grabbing text from a span

Tags: c#, webrequest, webresponse

I tried this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Danish to English: ");
            string tittyfuck = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Beep();
            WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest.Create("http://translate.google.com/#da/en/" + tittyfuck);
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream data = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            string html;

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine() != null))
                {
                    if (line == "<span class=\"hps\">")
                    {
                        Console.Beep();
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so I try that but I get these errors:

> Error 1   'System.Net.WebRequest.Create(System.Uri)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'  C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  18  52  ConsoleApplication1

and

> Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'   C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  27  32  ConsoleApplication1

As you can probably tell, I'm trying to open a request to translate.google.com with the text after the link, which then grabs the text that's printed to the  which is the translated text.. It's basically a translator.
Please help.

Comment: [I wouldn't check that into source control if I were you!](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Davecpp.aspx)

Comment: You have strange naming conventions for your String...

Comment: `new WebRequest.Create` should be `WebRequest.Create`

Comment: @Stijn I tried that but then got `Error 1 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Net.WebRequest' C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 18 37 ConsoleApplication1`

Answer (score 1):

Line 18:

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new URI("http://translate.google.com/#da/en/" + tittyfuck));
```

Line 27:

```
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the new keyword, and set other parenthesis.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Danish to English: ");
            string tittyfuck = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Beep();
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://translate.google.com/#da/en/" + tittyfuck);
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream data = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            string html;

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line == "<span class=\"hps\">")
                    {
                        Console.Beep();
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ran the program successfully, but didn't come with any output :(

Comment: Try adding a `Console.ReadLine();` to the end of the program. That way you see the output until you press enter. The programm closes before you have a chance to view the output. Thus add `Console.ReadLine();` so the program waits for you to press enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use google translate in this way because the translation is requested by javascript, you can try with a webbrowser or buying some characters for using the translate api

Another way is parsing the result of the request(http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?....) , that is in json style